# After moving files to SD card, mediaserver keeps drinking battery juice until next reboot

Tags: external-sd, battery, sd-card

Even if I move **just one** voice record (.ogg) or movie/picture file towards the SD card, the **Android *mediaserver/system_server* keeps draining the battery,** 2% per minute, and heating the device up rapidly, **until next reboot.**

But ***rebooting* to solve problems is against the Linux philosophy.**

- What exactly causes that problem?
- How can I fix this problem without rebooting?.

Comment: Hard to say without additional details. You could [investigate the logs](/tags/logging/info) to find at least some hints. Please let us know about your findings, so we can try to help.

Answer (score 1):

IME on much older Android versions, this is often a symptom of a corrupt SD card filesystem, which gets the media scanner "stuck" trying to read a file that is unreadable. Try scanning the SD card in another computer (using `fsck` or similar).

Comment: I will try it out.